# Counting list of words in c++

Tags: c++

Now I'm dealing with UVA problem 10420-List of Conquests (link : http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=1361) . To make it to the point I'll make the condition on the problem simpler . You just need to count how many words inputted. For example you must input all of these.

```
Spain
England
England
France
```

And output how many times that word inputted. It must be outputted ALPHABETICALLY.

```
England 2
France  1
Spain   1
```

Since I don't know which words will come out how I'll count the words with this condition in c++ ?

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I'm thinking using vector, but I can't figure it out how. Too complicated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there is usually used standard container `std::map<std::string, size_t>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, size_t> m;
   std::string word;

   while ( std::cin >> word ) ++m[word];

   for ( const auto &p : m ) std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

You should press either Ctrl + Z (in Windows) or Ctrl + D (in Unix) that to finish the input of words.

Or you could use function `std::getline` instead of `operator >>`

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, size_t> m;
   std::string word;

   while ( std::getline( std::cin, word ) && !word.empty() ) ++m[word];

   for ( const auto &p : m ) std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

In this case that to finish the input you need to enter an empty string that is to press simply ENTER key.

If the input is

```
Spain
England
England
France
```

The output will be

```
England 2
France  1
Spain   1
```

Comment: So if you use ++m[word] the index will be created automatically like push_back() function if word could'nt found in index before??

Comment: @user3022713 If an element with the given string used as an index does not exist it will be created.